# JSON.parse returns [object] from JSON

Tags: node.js

I'm using a npm package called `request` to make a http request to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Jur%C4%8Dkova+cesta+225&key=AIzaSyChkPdCaAaVZwYof8ZbKspokuYt41NlJ_0

Now I want to parse the data I receive in order to extract the LAT/LONG and write it into my database. But so far all I get as output to console is:

```
[ { address_components:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ],
    formatted_address: 'Breznikova ulica 15, 1230 Domžale, Slovenia',
    geometry:
     { location: [Object],
       location_type: 'ROOFTOP',
       viewport: [Object] },
    place_id: 'ChIJR2mtdUc0ZUcRv5nXK0zEx7M',
    types: [ 'street_address' ] },
  { address_components:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ],
    formatted_address: 'Breznikova ulica 15, 1000 Ljubljana, Slovenia',
    geometry:
     { location: [Object],
       location_type: 'ROOFTOP',
       viewport: [Object] },
    place_id: 'ChIJ19Ax9OPMekcRoPvkJ6SKNEg',
    types: [ 'street_address' ] },
  { address_components:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ],
    formatted_address: 'Breznikova ulica 15, 2000 Maribor, Slovenia',
    geometry:
     { location: [Object],
       location_type: 'ROOFTOP',
       viewport: [Object] },
    place_id: 'ChIJDUicXFd2b0cRYrf99vgTPBs',
    types: [ 'street_address' ] } ]
```

here's the extract of my code that produces this from my server.js file:

```
//get lat and long before saving from gmaps API
//build gmaps API URL
var urlAddress = shop.address.replace(/ /gi, '+');
var urlAPIKey = '&key=AIzaSyChkPdCaAaVZwYof8ZbKspokuYt41NlJ_0';
var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=';
url = url.concat(urlAddress).concat(urlAPIKey);
//make a request
request({
    uri: url,
    method:"GET",
    timeout: 100000
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        var gmaps = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(gmaps.results);
});
```

if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong that would be great. If I try to output the object it just returns undefined.

Comment: What is that output wrong?

Comment: @torazaburo because when I try to acces the object, for instance gmaps.results.address_components it just returns undefined

Comment: @mithril_knight, checked out util.inspect, displays the object properly now, now I need to find out how to call it. Thanks for now, you can write it up as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it appears as [Object] is for readability, if you want to show a full dump of the results, you have to pass it through JSON.stringify first.

As to access the address_components, the results is an array, so you'll have to access them for a specific element of that array (e.g. `gmaps.results[0].address_components`)

Comment: well yeah, you should iterate over `gmaps.results`, something like:

`gmaps.results.forEach(function(location) {
    console.log(location.address_components);
  });`

Comment: Is there a way to override the default behavior to see all data in the console.log?