# Node.js - Why does JSON.parse obfuscate objects in response body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

When I use JSON.parse and log out some fetched data with the `require` module, nested objects are logged `[Object]`. Here is an example (currently using Node version 10.15):

```js
const request = require("request");

const url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript.json";

request(url, (error, response) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(response.body);
  console.log(data)
});
```

```js
{ kind: 'Listing',
  data:
   { modhash: '',
     dist: 26,
     children:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ],
     after: 't3_bf4cl6',
     before: null } }
```

I was looking at this question: [JSON.parse returns [object] from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282265/json-parse-returns-object-from-json)

The person asking is curious why after JSON.parse, objects get logged as `[Object]`. The top answer states that the reason JSON.parse hides the data is for readability. But the answer doesn't explain a way to override the default behavior.

How do I get JSON.parse to log the full data? Is there a way to override the default behavior?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `JSON.parse()`. That returns a JavaScript object, and you're logging it out through the `console` mechanism. *That* is what's responsible for showing you the object value that way.

Comment: You can try `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`, or write your own function to traverse the object graph and dump out the value exactly how you want to see it.

Comment: You might want to console.log(util.inspect(body))

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object

Comment: @Pointy `console.dir` still logs out the JSON in the same way (with [Object])

Comment: @JoelHoelting OK well that `util.inspect()` thing that a couple other people pointed out seems like what you want.

Comment: @teroi: `console.log(util.inspect(data, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));` did what I wanted. I really don't understand the reason behind the obfuscation in console.log. It doesn't make my life easier (but that's a subjective opinion I suppose).

Comment: The `console()` mechanism has no standard; it's something that various JavaScript platforms provide (browsers, Node) but it's pretty much up to the individual implementors to decide what it does.

Comment: @Pointy: thanks for the clarification. I guess I would have to ask the node developers why they decided to implement `console()` to hide nested objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If logging `response.body` directly is not formatted the way you like, and that is why you are doing `JSON.parse`, then to log the full formatted object do
`console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(response.body), null, 2))`

Answer (score 3):

That's not JSON.parse, but console.log's default behavior for nested objects. You can use node's `util.inspect` to log with depth

```
const {inspect} = require('util');
console.log(inspect(obj, false, null, true));
```

Or as a function

```
function log(...data) {
  data.forEach(d => console.log(inspect(d, false, null, true)));
}
```